# get sub elements with xpath of lxml.html (Python)

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I am trying to get sub element with lxml.html, the code is as below.

```
import lxml.html as LH

html = """
<ul class="news-list2">
            <li>
            <div class="txt-box">
            <p class="info">Number:<label>cewoilgas</label></p>
            </div>
            </li>

            <li>
            <div class="txt-box">
            <p class="info">Number:<label>NHYQZX</label>
            </p>
            </div>
            </li>

        <li>
            <div class="txt-box">
            <p class="info">Number:<label>energyinfo</label>
            </p>
            </div>
            </li>

        <li>
            <div class="txt-box">
            <p class="info">Number:<label>calgary_information</label>
            </p>
            </div>
            </li>

        <li>
            <div class="txt-box">
            <p class="info">Number:<label>oilgas_pro</label>
            </p>
            </div>
            </li>

</ul>
"""
```

To get the sub element in li:

```
htm = LH.fromstring(html)
for li in htm.xpath("//ul/li"):
    print li.xpath("//p/label/text()")
```

Curious why the outcome is

```
['cewoilgas', 'NHYQZX', 'energyinfo', 'calgary_information', 'oilgas_pro']
['cewoilgas', 'NHYQZX', 'energyinfo', 'calgary_information', 'oilgas_pro']
['cewoilgas', 'NHYQZX', 'energyinfo', 'calgary_information', 'oilgas_pro']
['cewoilgas', 'NHYQZX', 'energyinfo', 'calgary_information', 'oilgas_pro']
['cewoilgas', 'NHYQZX', 'energyinfo', 'calgary_information', 'oilgas_pro']
```

And I also found the solution is:

```
htm = LH.fromstring(html)
for li in htm.xpath("//ul/li"):
    print li.xpath(".//p/label/text()")
```

the result is:

```
['cewoilgas']
['NHYQZX']
['energyinfo']
['calgary_information']
['oilgas_pro']
```

Should this be regarded as a bug for lxml? why xpath still match through the whole root element (ul) while it is under the sub-element (li)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not a bug, but is an *intended behavior*. If you start your expression with `//`, it does not matter if you call it on the root of the tree or on any element of the tree - it is going to be absolute and it is going to be applied from the root.

Just remember, if calling `xpath()` on an element and you want it to work relative from this element, always start your expressions with a dot which would refer to a *current node*.

By the way, absolutely (pun intended) the same happens in [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and it's `find_element(s)_by_xpath()`.

Comment: ok, if it is intended. Just accept this as it is... however, this is really confusing for newbies...

Comment: Actually I think the OP is right. This behaviour doesn't make any sense. If you call etree.tostring(li), you will get an xml fragment as string, while using li in a new xpath expression works on the original whole tree. This is very contraintuitive.

Answer (score 0):

> `//para` selects all the para descendants of the document root and thus
>   selects all para elements in the same document as the context node
>
> `//olist/item` selects all the item elements in the same document as the
>   context node that have an olist parent
>
> `.` selects the context node
>
> `.//para` selects the para element descendants of the context node

you can find more example in [XML Path Language (XPath)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)